# How to insert records as break times in a select in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Having this table in `Sql Server 2012`, I need to return the break times inserted in the right position.

I am able to use temporary tables if necessary.

> Break: It is the difference between the times, so I need a new
>   record representing the gaps.

**Table:**

```
╔════════════════╦════════════════╦══════════╦════════╗
║     Start      ║      End       ║ Duration ║  Type  ║
╠════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════╬════════╣
║ 1/06/2015 1:00 ║ 1/06/2015 1:30 ║ 0:30     ║ Logged ║
║ 1/06/2015 2:00 ║ 1/06/2015 3:00 ║ 1:00     ║ Logged ║
║ 1/06/2015 3:20 ║ 1/06/2015 4:00 ║ 0:40     ║ Logged ║
║ 1/06/2015 4:00 ║ NULL           ║          ║ Logged ║
╚════════════════╩════════════════╩══════════╩════════╝
```

**Result:**

```
╔════════════════╦════════════════╦══════════╦════════╗
║     Start      ║      End       ║ Duration ║  Type  ║
╠════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════╬════════╣
║ 1/06/2015 1:00 ║ 1/06/2015 1:30 ║ 0:30     ║ Logged ║
║ 1/06/2015 1:30 ║ 1/06/2015 2:00 ║ 0:30     ║ Break  ║
║ 1/06/2015 2:00 ║ 1/06/2015 3:00 ║ 1:00     ║ Logged ║
║ 1/06/2015 3:00 ║ 1/06/2015 3:20 ║ 0:20     ║ Break  ║
║ 1/06/2015 3:20 ║ 1/06/2015 4:00 ║ 0:40     ║ Logged ║
║ 1/06/2015 4:00 ║ NULL           ║          ║ Logged ║
╚════════════════╩════════════════╩══════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: Version of `Sql Server`?

Comment: Sql Server 2012 @GiorgiNakeuri

Comment: How are the breaks determined?

Comment: @ewan by breaks I mean the differences between the times (gaps).

Comment: What do you mean by "memory tables"? SQL Server 2012 doesn't have in memory OLTP. If you are referring to table variables that distinction is a myth. They are no more in memory than #temp tables.

Comment: @MartinSmith I fixed it, I mean #temp tables. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      StartTime DATETIME ,
      EndTime DATETIME,
      EmpID int    
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( '1/06/2015 1:00', '1/06/2015 1:30', 1 ),
        ( '1/06/2015 2:00', '1/06/2015 3:00', 1 ),
        ( '1/06/2015 3:20', '1/06/2015 4:00', 1 ),
        ( '1/06/2015 4:00', NULL, 1 ),
        ( '1/06/2015 1:00', '1/06/2015 1:20', 2 ),
        ( '1/06/2015 2:10', '1/06/2015 3:10', 2 ),
        ( '1/06/2015 3:20', '1/06/2015 3:30', 2 )


SELECT  StartTime, EndTime, Duration, EmpID, Logged
FROM    ( SELECT    StartTime ,
                    EndTime ,
                    DATEDIFF(mi, StartTime, EndTime) AS Duration ,                  
                    EmpID,                  
                    'Logged' AS Logged,
                    1 AS IncludeRow                  
          FROM      @t
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    EndTime ,
                    LEAD(StartTime) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY StartTime ) ,
                    DATEDIFF(mi, EndTime, LEAD(StartTime) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY StartTime ) ) ,                 
                    EmpID,
                    'Break' AS Logged,
                    CASE WHEN EndTime IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IncludeRow                  
          FROM      @t
        ) t
WHERE   (t.StartTime IS NOT NULL OR EndTime IS NOT NULL) AND (Duration > 0 OR t.IncludeRow = 1)
ORDER BY t.EmpID, t.StartTime
```

Output:

```
StartTime               EndTime                 Duration    EmpID   Logged
2015-01-06 01:00:00.000 2015-01-06 01:30:00.000 30          1       Logged
2015-01-06 01:30:00.000 2015-01-06 02:00:00.000 30          1       Break
2015-01-06 02:00:00.000 2015-01-06 03:00:00.000 60          1       Logged
2015-01-06 03:00:00.000 2015-01-06 03:20:00.000 20          1       Break
2015-01-06 03:20:00.000 2015-01-06 04:00:00.000 40          1       Logged
2015-01-06 04:00:00.000 NULL                    NULL        1       Logged
2015-01-06 01:00:00.000 2015-01-06 01:20:00.000 20          2       Logged
2015-01-06 01:20:00.000 2015-01-06 02:10:00.000 50          2       Break
2015-01-06 02:10:00.000 2015-01-06 03:10:00.000 60          2       Logged
2015-01-06 03:10:00.000 2015-01-06 03:20:00.000 10          2       Break
2015-01-06 03:20:00.000 2015-01-06 03:30:00.000 10          2       Logged
```

You are selecting first initial rows from table, and then `endtime` from each row with `startime` for next row(`LEAD` window function). Then you are `union`ing those results.

Comment: Great! One more thing, my last record normally has no endtime as the employee is still working, so how to add the last record together, in this sql it works perfectly but it doesnt bring my last record with endtime NULL.

Comment: Since and simple solution. One small improvement, if the time is continuous in 2 rows, it will still return a `'Break'` record. Good idea to add an additional check `AND (Type = 'Logged' OR (StartTime <> EndTime AND Type = 'Break'))` to remove such cases. + 1

Comment: @RogerOliveira, change where clause to  `WHERE   t.StartTime IS NOT NULL OR EndTime IS NOT NULL`

Comment: I am impressed! @GiorgiNakeuri

Comment: @RogerOliveira, added fix for continues dates also.

Comment: Great thanks, and if I have a column EmployeeId, how could I do it individually grouped by EmployeeId, I tried with your sql, it worked but it created breaks putting together between different employees, it should ignore and do this breaks by employeeid only. @GiorgiNakeuri

Comment: @RogerOliveira, added fix for employee, but this is last fix. Better ask new question.